# Angular component not updating when input changes value

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have a component that takes in a value from an object. I have the outer div subscribed to a behavior subject. When I update the behavior subjects value using `next()` the title of the container div updates but the inner component refuses to re-render. Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the behavior subject in my controller, this is called in the `ngOnInit` method and the update method that is called on button click in the html:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedRole$.next({ name: 'Current Permissions', permissions: this.getUserPermissions()
}

showRoleDetails(role: any): void {
  this.selectedRole$.next(role);
}
```

here is the parent component html this is where I am using async to subscribe to the behavior subject. the `selectedRole.name` updates perfectly but the inner `c-permissions-display` does not re-render:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedRole$ | async as selectedRole" class="col-8">
  <h5 class="font-weight-medium mb-0 text-gray-500 mb-4 permissions-title">{{ selectedRole.name }}</h5>
  <div class="section-container">
    <c-permissions-display [permissions]="selectedRole.permissions"></c-permissions-display>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the `c-permissions-display` component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilityService } from 'src/app/canopy-common/services/utility.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'c-permissions-display',
  templateUrl: './permissions-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./permissions-display.component.scss']
})
export class PermissionsDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() permissions: any[];
  formattedPermissions: any[];

  constructor(
    private util: UtilityService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formattedPermissions = this.formatPermissionsArray();
  }

  private formatPermissionsArray(): any {
    return stuff
  }
}
```

if I place a console log in the `ngOnInit` it calls once when the page loads but never again after calling `next()` on the behavior subject. I know I can get this to work if I implement `OnChanges` and then the `ngOnChanges()` method but I should not have to do that it should update and re-render on its own if its input changes value. Unless they changed that in angular 9

Comment: Why don't you use directly `permissions` into your child component ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing value to child component. you can pass observable to child component and subscribe inside child component so that whenver value changes in parent component child component get notified.

**Try this**

**parent.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="selectedRole$ | async as selectedRole" class="col-8">
  <h5 class="font-weight-medium mb-0 text-gray-500 mb-4 permissions-title">{{ selectedRole.name }}</h5>
  <div class="section-container">
    <c-permissions-display [permissions]="selectedRole$"></c-permissions-display>
  </div>
</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class PermissionsDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() permission = new BehaviorSubject(null);
   formattedPermissions: any[];

  constructor(
    private util: UtilityService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.permission.subscribe(permission=>{
        this.formattedPermissions = this.formatPermissionsArray();
    })

  }

  private formatPermissionsArray(): any {
    return stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i remember it is because selectedRole.permission is an array and angular can't know if a value  inside this array is changing or not.

So to make the array refresh too, you must overwrite the permission array with a new one. Something like selectedRole.permission = [new permission array ].

This way angular should be able to detect the change and refresh the view.

Comment: even if I change the input of the permissions component to be the `selectedRole` it still won't update